# Strange characters when the output of `ls` is redirected to a file

Tags: io-redirection, ls, escape-characters, special-characters

I want to list the components of the current working directory in a text file

```
ls -1 > textfile
```

Output looks fine with more.

```
1010661085645
1010729039145
1010747080245
1010849051345
1010859053445
1011046075845
```

However when I view this textfile with emacs, several strange characters appear

```
[0m[01;34m1010661085645[0m
[01;34m1010729039145[0m
[01;34m1010747080245[0m
[01;34m1010849051345[0m
[01;34m1010859053445[0m
[01;34m1011046075845[0m
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: look like a end of line issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those "strange characters" are escape sequences for coloring the output.

This will print that number in blue color:

```
echo -e '\033[01;34m1010729039145\033[0m'
```

See `man console_codes` for more details.

---

You can tell `ls` in which cases it shall output colors:

```
   --color[=WHEN]
          colorize the output; WHEN can be 'never', 'auto', or 'always' (the default); more info below
```

Looks like your `ls` is actually an alias for `ls --color=always`. (Type `type ls` to verify.)

Usually `ls --color=auto` will do the right thing: It will print colors on screen but no into files.

---

If you really want the color in your file, your have to decide, if you want to see the actual escape sequences or the interpreted colors.

For example the `less` command will default to printing the actual sequences, but you can tell it to show the colors instead with the `-R` option:

```
   -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
          Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form.
```

Try `less textfile` vs. `less -R textfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some misconfigurations in emacs, try this:

```
M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on
```

Or add this line to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

You can see [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiColor) for more details.